# How to create table in SQL, united with other tables via cells?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union, create-table

Need to create a table, that has cells in which data update when united tables update. The scheme is below.
The default status value is None.
Please help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/581EL.png)

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please include some sample data in your question. Sounds like you need a view.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice a bit more detail next time as this is going to help us answer your question.

It sounds like you need data storage which will allow you to define a dataset and have this dataset respond to underlying changes in the set. You should try VIEWS. They allow you to write a query and retrieve the results similarly to a table.

you can read more about them here https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-views-tutorial.aspx/

Comment: Yes, I think you're right, but I can't make correct query.